# How can I write a python script to automatically copy files at a specified time without manual user execution?

Tags: python, file, copy

I'm looking to write an automatic file copying script that copies files from one directory to another at a specified time (i.e. Fridays at 4pm). I can think of a few ways to approach this but was wondering if anyone has ever tried something similar to this and if python would be able to "run itself" at a given time, if not executed directly by a user.

If this is not possible, does anyone here know of a better software/platform to use?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [schedule](https://schedule.readthedocs.io) package.

It is an in-process scheduler for periodic jobs (if you don't want to mess with `cron` or other similar system tools).

An example:

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every().hour.do(job)
schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)
schedule.every().monday.do(job)
schedule.every().wednesday.at("13:15").do(job)
schedule.every().minute.at(":17").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Okay great! Thank you for the quick reply. I will give this a try.

Answer (score 1):

Most operating systems support some type of scheduling. Once you've created your python script for copying files you should be able to create a scheduled job to execute it whenever you want. For example, if you are on Windows you can create a `.bat` file that runs your python script, e.g.

```
python my_python.py
```

Alternatively, you could handle all of your file copying in the `.bat` file itself and never need python, since batch handles file copying pretty well. Either way, you can then use ***Task Scheduler*** to run the `.bat` file on some schedule (I don't know the applications to use for Linux and Mac, but they will have something with similar capabilities).

Comment: This sounds like exactly something I'm looking for. Thanks!